# Analysing Dijkstra Algorithm by using different varieties of Data Structure

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, shortest-path

### Question

> I want to analyse  Dijkstra  Algorithm by using different varieties of Data Structure.

### My solution

> 1. Adjacency **matrix** to Store the Graph and **Binary heap** for Priority Queue.
>
>    > $O(V\,\,log\,V+V^{2}\,\,log \,\,V)=O(V^{2}\,\,log \,\,V)$.

**Explanation-:**

> In Binary Heap we have $O(log\,\,V)$ for both **Extract min** and **decrease key**.

So Extract min for $V$ vertex =$O(V\,\,log \,\,V)$ and $E$ times **decrease key**,but here graph is dense (Adjacency matrix) so $E=V^{2}$ so total decrease key=$O(V^{2}\,\,log \,\,V)$

---

> 2. Adjacency **matrix** to Store the Graph and **fibonacci heap** for Priority Queue.
>
>    > $O(V\,\,log\,V+V^{2})=O(V^{2})$.

**Explanation-:**

> In Fibonacci Heap we have $O(log\,\,V)$ for  **Extract min** and $O(1)$ for **decrease key**.

So Extract min for $V$ vertex =$O(V\,\,log \,\,V)$ and $E$ times **decrease key**,but here graph is dense (Adjacency matrix) so $E=V^{2}$ so total decrease key=$O(V^{2})$

---

> 3. Adjacency **matrix** to Store the Graph and **Sorted Linked List** for Priority Queue.
>
>    > $O(V\,\,*V^{}+V^{2}\,\,V)=O(V^{3})$.

**Explanation-:**

> In Sorted Linked list  we have $O(V)$ for both **Extract min** and $O(V)$ for **decrease key**.(NOT SURE)

So Extract min for $V$ vertex =$O(V^{2})$ and $E$ times **decrease key**,but here graph is dense (Adjacency matrix) so $E=V^{2}$ so total decrease key=$O(V^{2}*V)$

I am uncertain about point **1 and 2** and  confused regarding **sorted linked list's** priority queue.Is there some efficent  way through which i can optimize my algorithm.Can anyone please help me out to clear my confusion?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.